# Не работает гибернция, Ubuntu

Tags: linux

Включил гибернацию в Ubuntu 20.04, но при нажатии на кнопку `Hibernate` в меню происходит что то типо `Lock`, тоже самое происходит при команде `sudo systemctl hibernate`. В результате команды `sudo pm-hibernate` просто выключается и включается экран. Как можно поправить данную ситуацию?

В файле `/etc/default/grub` прописано

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p2"

Comment: Все вроде детально https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/спящий_режим У Вас Настройка гибернации в swap-файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказали в комментариях: [спищий режим](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC)

Я настраивал через swap раздел.

1. Запишите ваши параметры в файл настроек initramfs `echo "resume=UUID=<UUID> resume_offset=<offset>" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

В gparted можно найти UUID и offset (First sector)

[image]

2. и в конфиг GRUB `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<UUID> resume_offset=<offset>"
```

3. Обновите настройки GRUB и сгенерируйте новый initramfs:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

4. Перезагружаем
5. Проверьте работу гибернации с помощью команды pm-hibernate из пакета pm-utils `sudo pm-hibernate`
6. Если у вас все работает - переходите к следующему пункту. Если нет — воспользуйтесь утилитой uswsusp `sudo s2disk`
7. Если у вас все заработало - радуйтесь, если нет - придется конфигурировать uswsusp `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -pmedium uswsusp`
8. Если заработало, заменяем вызов pm-hibernate на s2disk:
   `echo "SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp" | sudo tee -a /etc/pm/config.d/module`

Если гибернация заработала, то остается только активировать кнопку «Спящий режим» в меню выключения. Для этого:

Измените настройки policitykit `sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

В блоке:

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=no
 
[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=no
```

Замените измените в них параметр *ResultActive* с **no** на **yes**.

Если гибернация работает по вызову `pm-hibernate`, но не работает по кнопке «Спящий режим» в меню выключения, то, возможно, проблема в том, что эта кнопка вызывает команду `systemctl hibernate`, которая по умолчанию не поддерживает `uswsusp`

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service
```

Заменяем

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate
```

на

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 's2disk && run-parts --regex .\* -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep'
```